# How to get Serial Number...etc. of Windows XP Home with Java or Command Line

Tags: java, command-line, windows-xp, wmi, serial-number

I have a Java program which is using WMIC to get certain information about the hardware of the PC. The problem is, Windows XP Home edition does not have WMIC. I did some research and I did not find any way besides WMI for getting the information I want. I also looked into installing WMIC on the machine in question but I did not find any thing down that road ether. The information I want includes: Serial #, Model #, Manufacturer, OS Version...and other things. Primarily I want the Serial Number.

I prefer to use Java or the Command Line.

Comment: Perhaps [Hyperic Sigar](http://freshmeat.net/projects/hyperic-sigar/) has what you want?  Not sure.

Comment: XP Home edition does not support wmi. you might want to look into windows API. http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/380058-how-can-i-get-serial-numper-hard-disk-using-api or http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/DeviceIoControl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the serial number but with a mix of [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) and [Nmap](http://nmap.org/book/man.html) you can gather a lot of informations such as OS Version, Manufacturer etc. For instance with the command `nmap -A -O ip` it's very easy to retrieve OS details and Manufacturer. With SNMP instead, as you can read on the [sysDescr OID description](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1) you should gather the following informations:

> A textual description of the entity. This value should include the
>   full name and version identification of the system's hardware type,
>   software operating-system, and networking software. It is mandatory
>   that this only contain printable ASCII characters

Comment: My project has been closed but your information could be helpful on future projects. Thanks!